# Connect to vpn with VM as middleman

Tags: networking, vpn, virtualhost

I am assuming it is possible to connect to a virtual machine as a VPN service from my host machine, but I would assume like any other vpn service I would need to go through my router with some rule to forward any incoming traffic to the vpn service? My question is am I able to bypass the router and connect to the VM from my host machine?

The real issue is (hopefully to avoid an X-Y problem) Is I need to connect to an outside vpn however the certificate to connect can't not be generated on linux machines (I don't know why or how, this is what I was told by the admin on the phone...). My idea is that I can connect to the vpn from the virtual machine, and connect to the virtual machine so I can essentially be granted access to the network from the host machine?

VM Os:   Win10 using Cisco AnyConnect

Host Os: Arch Linux using openconnect

Comment: The creation of the certificate should be an onetime event, is there no opportunity to move the certificate to your Linux box after it has been generated? Am I getting this right that you try establishing the VPN connection inside the VM and forwarding your hosts' traffic through the VM?

Comment: yes that was the idea

Comment: For the sake of correctness, please take this question to [su] as your use case does not seems to be related to information technology systems in a business environment. When doing so, please include your Linux OS, the target OS of the VM as well as the software you prefer to use for virtualization.

Comment: Ok sorry about that!

Comment: I am sorry I cannot comment on [su], yet. Could you include the VPN client you need to use with windows in your new question, please?